# Array Filter in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

i have json array get from http web api, i want to filter this array:

```
    [
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 4,
"id_segmen": 1,
"segmen": "ppu",
"jumlah": 3953,
"target": 900000
},
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 3,
"id_segmen": 2,
"segmen": "bpu",
"jumlah": 45,
"target": 500000
},
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 3,
"id_segmen": 1,
"segmen": "ppu",
"jumlah": 8752,
"target": 900000
}]
```

i need to filter or select for get all where id_segmen=1. 
this is my expectation :

```
 [
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 4,
"id_segmen": 1,
"segmen": "ppu",
"jumlah": 3953,
"target": 900000
}]
```

my current http.get is as below:

```
this.http.get<JuResponse>(environment.url + '/cps/' + year + '/' + month + '/' + kanwil + '/' + cabang).
   subscribe(data => {
       let filteredValues = data.filter((data) => value.id_segmen == 1); 
       console.log(filteredValues); 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
    if (arrayData[i].id_segmen == 1) {
        result.push(arrayData[i]);
    }
}
```

Try this

```js
var arrayData= [
{
 "bulan": "4",
 "tahun": "2017",
 "id_program": 4,
 "id_segmen": 1,
 "segmen": "ppu",
 "jumlah": 3953,
 "target": 900000
},
{
 "bulan": "4",
 "tahun": "2017",
 "id_program": 3,
 "id_segmen": 2,
 "segmen": "bpu",
 "jumlah": 45,
 "target": 500000
},
{
 "bulan": "4",
 "tahun": "2017",
 "id_program": 3,
 "id_segmen": 1,
 "segmen": "ppu",
 "jumlah": 8752,
 "target": 900000
}]
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {
 if (arrayData[i].id_segmen == 1) {
  result.push(arrayData[i]);
 }
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code, items is your JSON from WebAPI and fiteredItem is an array of objects which has id_segmen=1

```
this.filteredItem= this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.id_segmen ===1);
      })
```

Comment: thanks @prathivi, could you explain more detail, iam new in JS

Comment: The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. check this link for documentation on filter method in Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: mark this as your correct answer if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter`

```
let filteredArray = this.myArray.filter(item => item.id_segment===1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the native javascript [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, like this way:

```
let filteredValues = result.filter((value) => value.id_segmen == 1);
```

this way, 
*filteredValues* will contain only your values with id_segmen == 1.

Comment: that's why you need to adjust your variables names to the example i wrote. can you please share your code in your question (by editing it, for example)?

Comment: ` this.http.get<JuResponse>(environment.url + '/cps/' + year + '/' + month + '/' + kanwil + '/' + cabang)
            .subscribe(data => {let filteredValues = data.filter((data) => value.id_segmen == 1);

                
                    console.log(this.filteredValues);
                }`

Comment: Okay, i suppose your piece of code it's not working. What does contains 'data'? What's the name of the array you are trying to get id_segmen == 1?

Comment: by the way you should use console.log(filteredValues) instead of console.log(this.filteredValues).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript Filters for this purpose

```js
var a = [
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 4,
"id_segmen": 1,
"segmen": "ppu",
"jumlah": 3953,
"target": 900000
},
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 3,
"id_segmen": 2,
"segmen": "bpu",
"jumlah": 45,
"target": 500000
},
{
"bulan": "4",
"tahun": "2017",
"id_program": 3,
"id_segmen": 1,
"segmen": "ppu",
"jumlah": 8752,
"target": 900000
}];

var c = a.filter(function(val){
  return val.id_segmen == 1 ;
});
alert(JSON.stringify(c))
```

Comment: @YK.toe pls accept / thumbs up if it helped you, Thanks!